# Initialize rvalue reference member

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize a rvalue reference member in the following situations: `struct A` is a aggregate and `class B` has a user defined constructor so it is not an aggregate. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) here,

```cpp
struct A {
  int&& r;
};
A a1{7}; // OK, lifetime is extended
A a2(7); // well-formed, but dangling reference
```

The reference in my `struct A` should be correctly initialized and the temporary string should be extended, but it's not.
For my `class B`, in the same cppreference page:

> a temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer list persists only until the constructor exits, not as long as the object exists. (note: such initialization is ill-formed as of DR 1696).
>   (until C++14)

But I am still getting problem with MSVC with `/std:c++latest`. Am I missing anything?

```cpp
struct A
{
    std::string&& ref;
};

class B
{
    std::string&& ref;
public:
    B(std::string&& rref):ref(std::move(rref)){}
    void print() {std::cout<<ref<<'\n';}
};

int main()
{
    A a{ std::string{"hello world"} };
    std::cout<<a.ref<<'\n'; //garbage in MSVC with c++latest, correct in GCC9.2
    B b{ std::string{"hello world"} };
    b.print(); //same
}
```

EDIT: Please tell me if I am getting dangling reference in these two cases in the first place. And for MSVC, the version is the latest update, v19.24.28315

EDIT2: OK I am actually confused by cppreference's explanation. I am not asking specificly for C++20. Please tell me under which C++ version, the code is well-formed or not.

EDIT3: Is there a proper way to initialize a rvalue reference member of a non-aggregate class? Since bind it to a temporary in a member initializer list is ill-formed (until C++14, does it mean it is good since C++14?) and passing a temporary to a constructor expecting an rvalue cannot extend its lifetime twice.

Comment: The quote does not support your contention that `A a1{7};` extends the life of the temporary.

Comment: `/std:c++latest` does not specify the *C++ standard* (which may be pretty relevant in this question). The *latest* c++ version depends on the MSVC version. It may be better if you can specify the C++ version

Comment: Fwiw, reference members should be avoided.  This is doubly so for rvalue references since they do **not** extend the lifetime of temporaries when they are class members

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It is new C++20 parenthesized aggregate initialization syntax. GCC trunk already supports it: https://godbolt.org/z/K-4CXL

Comment: @NathanOliver Could you provide a reference for rvalue references not extending lifetime of temporaries when they are class members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class `A` is an aggregate type, but `B` isn't, because it has a user-provided constructor and a private non-static member.

Therefore `A a{ std::string{"hello world"} };` is aggregate initialization which *does* extend the lifetime of the temporary through reference binding to that of `a`.

On the other hand `B` is not aggregate initialization. It calls the user-provided constructor, which passes on the reference. Passing on references does not extend the lifetime of the temporary. The `std::string` object will be destroyed when the constructor of `B` exits.

Therefore the later use of `a` has well-defined behavior, while that of `b` will have undefined behavior.

This holds for all C++ versions since C++11 (before that the program would be obviously ill-formed).

If your compiler is printing garbage for `a` (after removing `b` from the program so that it doesn't have undefined behavior anymore), then this is a bug in the compiler.

---

Regarding edit of question:

There is no way to extend the lifetime of a temporary through binding to a reference member of a non-aggregate class.

Relying on this lifetime extension at all is very dangerous, since you would likely not get any error or warning if you happen to make the class non-aggregate in the future.

If you want the class to always retain the object until its lifetime ends, then just store it by-value instead of by-reference:

```
class B
{
    std::string str;
public:
    B(std::string str) : str(std::move(str)) {}
    void print() { std::cout << str << '\n'; }
};
```

Comment: 1. After deleteing ``b``, MSVC still printing garbage. (Actually it's printing an empty line.) No matter with ``default`` or c++14 17 or latest. 2. Why initializing ``b`` does not extend the life time of the temporary? 3. How about default initializing b with ``B():ref(std::string{"hello world"}){}``?

Comment: @szppeter In the initialization of `b` the temporary is first bound to the reference in the constructor parameter, which "extends" its lifetime until the end of the full-expression containing the constructor call. But binding another reference to the temporary does not further extend the lifetime. Initialization with `B():ref(std::string{"hello world"}){}` is what the quote in your question is referring to. It is ill-formed since C++14 and did *not* extend the lifetime beyond the duration of the constructor call before that.

Comment: The quote is ``until C++14``, not ``since C++14``

Comment: @szppeter It is "*until C++14*", because since C++14 binding a reference to a temporary in a member initializer list is ill-formed, so talking about whether it extends temporary lifetime doesn't make sense anymore. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list.

Comment: @walnut Great answer. Can I also ask: in the case where `a` (of type `A`) is formed from aggregate initialization from a temporary, is the temporary's lifetime still controlled by the stack? Could (a copy of) `a` be returned from a function and used?